# Can't center image

Tags: css, html, center

I cannot center a image in a `div`. How can I center the image given the following markup?

html code is as follows:

```html
<div id='post-area' style='background:#000; padding:20px 0;'>
  <a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='example-big.png'>
    <img src='example.png'  />
  </a>
</div>
```

css code is as follows:

```CSS
#post-area {
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000;
  text-align:left;
  width:450px;
  height:auto;
  font-family:Meera
  clear:both;
  margin-top:20px;
  letter-spacing:normal;
}

#post-area img {
  max-width:250px;
  height:auto;
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

If there is any way to do this

Comment: *Note:* Your CSS `font-family` property is missing a semi-colon. Also, HTML should have double quotes, not single quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you just want to center the image horizontally, you could change text-align:left to text-align: center.

Comment: This isn't working anymore. I don't think this will work if the parent `div` is `position: absolute;`

Answer (score 3):

**HTML**

```
<div id='post-area' style='background:#000; padding:20px 0;'>
  <a class='fancybox' rel='group' href='example-big.png'>
    <img src='http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/colourful-logo/18.jpg'  />
  </a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#post-area {
  font-size:13px;
  color:#000;
  text-align:center;
  width:450px;
  height:auto;

  font-family:Meera;
  clear:both;
  margin-top:20px;
  letter-spacing:normal;
}

#post-area img {
  max-width:250px;
  height:auto;
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto;
```

}

see the demo :- http://tinkerbin.com/gWYGnA6m

Answer (score 2):

Try with `text-align:center` in CSS of `#post-area`.

Here is [your example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mnqjj/) with center aligned `img`.